# Can not use localtunnel(localtunnel.me) in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Im 1st time use ubuntu and I got a problem when use localtunnel. I can install it normally but can't run it. The terminal said

```
The program 'lt' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install looptools
```

I can install sailsjs globally and run it properly but this package doesn't. Can you give me a solution to run localtunnel on my computer?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you `sudo apt install looptools`?

Comment: Did you try `npm install -g localtunnel` ?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/lt` work?

Comment: I have already install with `sudo npm install -g localtunnel`, it install successfully and `/usr/local/bin/lt` didnt work for me!